# TQL statement for inserting json integer array to table rows

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

How do I insert a JSON integer array to a table column in SQL server. Suppose I have the following json variable:

```
declare @jsonArray as varchar(max);
set @jsonArray = '[1,2,3,4]';
```

How do I insert the integer values into a table's integer type column using some of the SQL server JSON statements/functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use openjson to split the JSON data-**

```
declare @jsonArray as varchar(max);
set @jsonArray = '[1,2,3,4]';
SELECT Value FROM OPENJSON(@jsonArray)

Value
-----------
1
2
3
4

(4 rows affected)
```

**Please use like below**

```
declare @jsonArray as varchar(max);
set @jsonArray = '[1,2,3,4]';
INSERT INTO yourTableName(ColumnName)
SELECT Value FROM OPENJSON(@jsonArray)
```

Read more from - https://msbiskills.com/2018/01/22/new-t-sql-features-in-sql-server-2016-xii-openjson-function-sql-server/

Comment: Thank you! I had seen some very complex json object examples, but didn't find anything simple as an integer array. Also didn't know about the "Value" keyword. That's something new for me!